# clear singleton pattern concept please

Tags: .net, singleton

I want to make connection with sql server DB and maintain in singleton pattern. So is this functionality inbuilt in dot net ? or we mannually have to write the code for this scenario?

Comment: What are the reasons to use the singleton pattern? Are you worried that too many connection get opened at once? I am asking because maybe you don't need it at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting db connection through singleton class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814206/getting-db-connection-through-singleton-class)

Comment: The usual way is not to use a singleton, but to use connection pooling. The good thing here is that connection pooling is built in .NET and works out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy loaded singleton example

```
public sealed class Singleton
```

{
    Singleton()
    {
    }

```
public static Singleton Instance
{
    get
    {
        return Nested.instance;
    }
}

class Nested
{
    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Nested()
    {
    }

    internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [`sqlHelper`](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid5F6557C27DD01854BC85719A8B8A25A468393A08.aspx?s=sqlhelper#L5) class will do work for you which is related to database connections

Comment: @Lalit - sqlhelper contains all static methods so there is no need to bother about object creation it manage sqlconnection internally

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814206/getting-db-connection-through-singleton-class).