# Is it appropriate to use the singleton pattern on a Web Service class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, singleton

I currently have a class `MyClass` with a constructor that logs into a Web Service, returns a Session ID if it doesn't already have one, and saves it in a `private static SomeWebService service` attribute.

In my controller, a call would look like `new MyClass().doSomething()` which in turn would end up calling `service.someWebServiceMethod()` within `MyClass`.

Is it appropriate to continue creating a new `MyClass` for every call, seeing as I'm saving the session itself as `static`? Would it be more ideal to make `SomeWebService service` non-static and implement the Singleton pattern instead? Does it even matter?

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814206/getting-db-connection-through-singleton-class) as I was about to switch to Singleton and now I'm unsure which approach to take.

Comment: The question isn't whether it's appropriate, but whether it's appropriate in this case. If you don't have a compelling reason to, don't. In fact, I'd be concerned about storing that static value at all, although I don't know exactly what it's for.

Comment: Agreed, I phrased it this way after seeing the advice "never use a singleton on a database connection", so my question is "Can I use a singleton on a web service connection?" The reason that static value exists is because it stores a session for all future web service calls to use. If it wasn't static, it would have to have a new session ID generated for every call.

Comment: What does the web service you're calling do with that session?

Comment: It uses the session ID stored within to authenticate requests for information via any other method than the Login() call.